# What is the meaning of an "award citation"?

Tags: awards, acm

In the details of an ACM conference, the following is mentioned:

> The best paper in each track will receive an award citation.

I want to know, what they mean by "award citation" here and what winning the "best paper" award would entail in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a different meaning of the word 'citation' to the one we're used to. Merriam-Webster (e.g.) gives [an alternative definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/citation):

> 3: **MENTION:** such as
> ***a***
> : a formal statement of the achievements of a person receiving an academic honor
>
> ***b***
> : specific reference in a military dispatch to meritorious performance of duty 
>       *a citation for bravery*

So an "award citation" simply means that they publicly announce/advertise the name of the winner. Probably it implies that there will be no significant physical or monetary prize, other than (perhaps) a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

From: [ACM Website](https://www.acm.org/conferences/best-paper-awards)

> ###### Conferences Best Paper Awards
>
> Best Paper Awards are presented at many ACM conferences to authors whose work represents groundbreaking research in their respective areas. By recognizing these select papers for their ingenuity and importance, ACM highlights some of the theoretical and practical innovations that are likely to shape the future of computing.

Being accepted for a "best paper" at an ACM conference is in layman's terms "really good."  (Caveat, this somewhat depends on the specific ACM conference)

From: [Peer-Selected “Best Papers”—Are They Really That “Good”?](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0118446)

> ###### Results
>
> The probability that a best paper will receive more citations than a non best paper is 0.72 (95% CI = 0.66, 0.77) for the Scopus data, and 0.78 (95% CI = 0.74, 0.81) for the Scholar data. There are no significant changes in the probabilities for different years. Also, 51% of the best papers are among the top 10% most cited papers in each conference/year, and 64% of them are among the top 20% most cited.
>
> ###### Discussion
>
> There is strong evidence that the selection of best papers in Computer Science conferences is better than a random selection, and that a significant number of the best papers are among the top cited papers in the conference.

Per the first link, ACM also publishes lists of top papers.  Top papers are an "award" that can be put on resumes with varying levels of prestige based on the reviewer.  And, depending on the field of computation, ACM and its related publications / conferences are in the top 20, so good name / brand recognition.  All as of the time of this answer 1/8/2023:

- Theoretical CS: [Number 1, 2, 4, 8, 18](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_theoreticalcomputerscience)
- Data Mining: [Number 1, 4, 12, 15](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_datamininganalysis)
- Software Systems: [Number 1(with IEEE), 5, 7, 9(with IEEE), 10](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_softwaresystems)
- Computer Graphics: [Number 1, 7, 15](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computergraphics)
- Security and Crypto: [Number 1, 16](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computersecuritycryptography)
- Game Theory: [Number 2](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_gametheorydecisionscience)
- Human Computer Interaction: [Number 3, 4, 6(with IEEE), 7, 10, 16](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_humancomputerinteraction)
- Databases: [Number 3, 6, 7, 8, 14, 20](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_databasesinformationsystems)
- Multimedia: [Number 4, 9, 13, 16, 20](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_multimedia)
- Hardware: [Number 5, 12 (with IEEE)](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computerhardwaredesign)
- Bioinformatics: [Number 7(with IEEE), 18](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_bioinformatics)
- Engineering and CS: [Number 10](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_enggeneral)
- Signal Processing: [Number 11(with IEEE)](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_signalprocessing)
- Systems: [Number 12(with IEEE), 16](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computingsystems)
- Robotics: [Number 12(with IEEE)](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_robotics)
- Networks and Wireless: [Number 19(with IEEE)](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computernetworkswirelesscommunication)